# Error updating changes svn

Tags: svn, working-copy

I have PHPStorm installed and i open a directory containing a PHP project with SVN. Under the SVN tab in the Changes i encounter the following error:

```
Error updating changes: svn: E155021: The client is too old to work with the working copy at "..." (format 31).
```

Some ideas? I have TortoiseSVN 1.7.7 installed, when i open the project the first time everything worked great, but on further opening the above error appear.

Comment: Phpstorm comes with an integrated svn client. It is possible that this integrated client it is too old. I don't know if it's possible to update it, maybe search in plugin updates? If you can't, you will have to do your subversion work via tortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Working copy format has changed in Subversion 1.8, so after upgrading
to TortoiseSVN 1.8 you should upgrade your working copies or checkout the new ones. After you've upgraded a working copy to the newer format, older Subversion clients will be
unable to work with the upgraded working copy.

So, you've upgraded your working copy to the new format (SVN 1.8). It seems that another SVN client on your system is SVN 1.8 (e.g. TortoiseSVN 1.8.0?), but PHPStorm is still 1.7.x. SVN 1.7 can't work with 1.8 working copy and vice-verse.

See ["Subversion 1.8 Release Notes | Upgrading the Working Copy"](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#wc-upgrade).

Answer (score 1):

I don't now the tool but in my case I move eclipse workspace place to another then problem is occured. For solving problem I checkout project form the svn repo. Then in old project I clean all svn files. (simple search .svn and delete ) then I copy the content to the just checkedout one my changes become visible and my project is up to date. This method can be applied for other annoying errors. 
Hope help someone

Answer (score 0):

For Phpstorm 1.7 I had similar problems. Dont try to checkout it with SVN >1.8. Like noted above, it does not seem to work. Checkout elsewhere ad update it. 
I did by:

```
-VCS => Operation PopUp (you will ne prompted to fill repository. Thats the goal)  
-(clear auth cache)
-(VCS => show history. You have to enter your credentials)
-VCS => Update
-Good Luck
```